# Regex to parse Javascript function call-like syntax

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have the following data posibilities

```
fnname()
fnname(value)
fnname(value,valueN)
```

I need a way to parse it with javascript regex to obtain an array

```
[fnname]
[fnname,value]
[fnname,value,valueN]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need to handle nested function calls as in `f(g(h(value)))`

Comment: no, just this data set

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I suspect OP showed `[` and `]` for array representation.

Comment: @anubhava yep, now only i realized that.

Comment: @anubhava yes [] means array representation. sorry if unclear.

Comment: Do `valueN` mean any value (e.g. numbers, quoted strings) or they are just identifiers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try matching rather than splitting,

```
> var re = /[^,()]+/g;
undefined
> var matches=[];
undefined
> while (match = re.exec(val))
... {
... matches.push(match[0]);
... }
5
> console.log(matches);
[ 'fnname', 'value', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4' ]
```

**OR**

```
> matches = val.match(re);
[ 'fnname',
  'value',
  'value2',
  'value3',
  'value4' ]
```

Comment: `matches = val.match(re)` seems simpler than looping.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
var matches = string.split(/[(),]/g).filter(Boolean);
```

- Regex `/[(),]/g` is used to split on any of these 3 characters in the character class
- `filter(Boolean)` is used to discard all empty results from resulting array

**Examples:**

```
'fnname()'.split(/[(),]/g).filter(Boolean);
//=> ["fnname"]

'fnname(value,value2,value3,value4)'.split(/[(),]/g).filter(Boolean);
//=> ["fnname", "value", "value2", "value3", "value4"]
```

Comment: `.filter(Boolean)` that's something new.

Answer (score 2):

Taking some inspiration from other answers, and depending on the rules for identifiers:

```
str.match(/\w+/g)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use split like so:

```
var val = "fnname(value,value2,value3,value4)";
var result = val.split(/[\,\(\)]+/);
```

This will produce:

```
["fnname", "value", "value2", "value3", "value4", ""]
```

Notice you need to handle empty entries :)
You can do it using Array.filter:

```
result = result.filter(function(x) { return x != ""; });
```

Comment: an empty value in the last that should not be there?

Comment: What's the point of escaping the comma or parentheses inside the character set? Also, this matches something like `"fname(),()((a)"`, which seems odd.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it in one line:

```
"fnname(value,value2,value3,value4)".split(/[\(,\)]/g).slice(0, -1);
```

Which will evaluate to

```
["fnname", "value", "value2", "value3", "value4"]
```